# Is there a computable list of the recent browser versions anywhere?

Tags: browser

I wonder if there is any service that provides a computable list (XML and/or JSON) of current browser versions and when they got updated the last time.

I would like to use that to inform people that they run an outdated version of their browser and if the most recent version of their browser is too old, they may switch to another one.

Comment: Not sure if there is, but you should definitely check modernizer: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Naah, modernizr detects JS features, not browsers.

Comment: just an idea, but using the feature detection you can get much more fine grained control over which browsers you support and which you don't.

Comment: I don't care about the browsers features at this point. I just want to say: hey, you are using IE8 which is from 2009. There is IE9 available, go update already!

Comment: Its meant to be used on a support page where we can automatically collect the users browser/pc configuration and get it sent to us.

I thought it would be a nice feature to give the user some automated suggestions right away before they file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you could have this information available somewhere in JSON or XML format, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers) has an excellent article on comparison of web browsers.